# SELECT with multiple WHERE conditions on same column and UNIQUE values

Tags: mysql, sql

I think this is an easy one, but I need some help to solve it:

```
id   product  option    suboption 
-----------------------------------
118     A       1           1 
119     A       2           2 
120     A       3           1 
121     B       1           2
122     B       2           2
123     B       3           1
124     C       1           1
125     C       2           2
126     C       3           1
```

I need to find all unique products where for option = 1 then suboption = 1, for option = 2 then suboption = 2, and for option = 3 then suboption = 1.

In this example, the ones that fullfil my request are products A and C.

How can I do this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  Here is one method:

```
select product
from t
where (option, suboption) in ( (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1) )
group by product
having count(distinct option) = 3;
```

In your example data, there is only one option per product.  If that is the case, then use:

```
having count(*) = 3
```

instead of the `count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by product:

```
select 
  product
from tablename
group by product
having
  sum(option = 1 and suboption = 1) > 0
  and
  sum(option = 2 and suboption = 2) > 0
  and
  sum(option = 3 and suboption = 1) > 0
```